# C# Json arrary reading

Tags: json

how to read json { "empdata": { "emp": [ { "DATE": "07.01.2021", "EMP_ID": "A001", "S_DATE": "2021-01-07T00:00:00.000+00:00", "Desig": "Engg" }, { "DATE": "08.01.2021", "EMP_ID": "A002", "S_DATE": "2021-01-07T00:00:00.000+00:00", "Desig": "Engg" } ] } } in c#

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 0):

//Create Class First

```
public class Emp    {
    public string DATE { get; set; } 
    public string EMP_ID { get; set; } 
    public DateTime S_DATE { get; set; } 
    public string Desig { get; set; } 
}

public class Empdata    {
    public List<Emp> emp { get; set; } 
}

public class Data{
    public Empdata empdata { get; set; } 
}
```

string JsonResponse="Your Json Data";

Data JsonData= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(JsonResponse);

JsonData Will Have all of Ur Data